# Give FTP access to a specific folder in my Mac Book Pro

Tags: macos, ftp, macbook-pro, macos-sierra

Hi I have a mac book pro and want to give me team member access via ftp to a specific folder in my system. We both are on the same network. Can anyone help me setup this?

I'm on Mac OS Sierra V10.12.4

Comment: If you're on the same network why not just use a file share which is probably already a built in feature? For FTP you'd need to look into setting up a full FTP server.

Comment: Yes I did enable that feature but other user can access all my folders including personal ones that I don't want to share

Comment: What feature? If they're able to access more than they should, you probably need to check your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the file sharing option in the Mac settings. [Set up a Mac to share folder](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21820?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: Please consider adding a summary of the content of the link, in case the link might be broken in the future.